# XML to PDF using FOP

Tags: pdf, data-conversion, xsl-fo, postscript

I'm trying to create Print PDF from xml Using FOP engine. In this I have to face the following challenge is to print .EPS images. After converting as .PS(Postscript) it is resolved but I can't able to retain the fonts I have mentioned in my FO file.

I'm converting the FO to PS using below commend

fop -c D:\Hari\fop\conf\fop.xconf -fo D:\Hari\2023\04-Apr\28-04-23\Assets\c01.fo -ps D:\Hari\2023\04-Apr\28-04-23\Assets\c01-fop.ps

While converting ps to PDF using Adobe acrobat i'm getting the bellow error.

%%[ Error: rangecheck; OffendingCommand: show ]%%

Stack:
(   )

%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%

Is there any way to resolve it.

fop -c D:\Hari\fop\conf\fop.xconf -fo D:\Hari\2023\04-Apr\28-04-23\Assets\c01.fo -ps D:\Hari\2023\04-Apr\28-04-23\Assets\c01-fop.ps

Comment: Would need to see the PostScript program (what you sent to Adobe Acrobat Distiller) to be able to comment. rangecheck is a possible, if somewhat unusual, error for the PostScript 'show' operator. Possible reasons listed in the PLRM are a character code indexing beyond the end of the Encoding array or the character mapping going out of bounds in other ways.